# Cómo usar AsyncTask en un fragmento

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

Tengo un fragmento con Google Maps que usa `Location` para realizar algunas operaciones. Este fragmento es llamado desde otro fragmento con un botón, es decir, cuando el botón se presiona se llama al fragmento del mapa y se realizan operaciones.

El problema es que falla por haber puntero vacío. Tengo que hacer que el fragmento con el botón espere a obtener señal del GPS para poder lanzar el siguiente fragmento y que no ocurra el fallo.

Lo he intentado con `AsyncTask` pero no sé muy bien qué poner. ¿Alguien me podría echar una mano?

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

Botón:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //Fragment fragment = null;


    getLocation getLocation = new getLocation();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.SearchButton:

            getLocation.execute();

            break;
    }
}
```

Y la clase `AsyncTask` (aquí es donde estoy perdido pues es mi primera vez con `AsyncTask`):

```
    public class getLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


    protected void doInBackground(String... strings) {


    }


    protected void onPreExecute(String... strings){

   }


    protected void onPostExecute(){
        Home activity = (Home) getActivity();//---> After app gets coordinates from anywhere, it launches next fragment with the map.
        if(activity != null)activity.openMapFragment();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te lo pongo de pseudocódigo, ya que hay mucha información al respecto en internet

```
        protected void doInBackground(String... strings) {
           // Aquí llamas a las operaciones de Location y todo lo que
           // tengas que hacer en background
        }


        protected void onPreExecute(String... strings){
           // Aquí enseñas el ProgressDialog 
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(){
            // Cierras el PogressDialog y haces todo lo que tengas que hacer
            Home activity = (Home) getActivity();  //---> After app gets coordinates from anywhere, it launches next fragment with the map.
            if (activity != null) {
                activity.openMapFragment();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Una Clase no podes llamarla `getLocation`, `get`, `do`, `set`, etc.. se usa para métodos, no para clases.

Te recomiendo usar AsyncTaskLoader y no AsyncTask, ya fue esa clase, es mejorada.

Referencias:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39837244/can-asynctaskloader-replace-asynctask
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html